# Transfer one column from one sql table to another based on unique records postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigdata

I have a two sql(postgres) tables, I need to insert one column from one table to another.
Note each table contains around 100 million of records

For instance my table schemas:

```
first_table:
id int, first_column int, second_column int, third_column;

second_table:
id int, fourth_column int;
```

Note id  column in both tables is primary key.

I need to get the following table:

```
first_table:
id int, first_column int, second_column int, third_column int, fourth_column int;
```

In few words, I need to merge this two tables based on id( primary key) column.

I have tried:

1. Add an empty column called fourth_column for first_table, and update it.

```
    UPDATE first_column AS f
           SET fourth_column = t.fourth_column
           FROM second_table AS t
           WHERE f.id = t.id;
```

This method works, but each sql tables contains around 100 million of records, and this solution takes a lot of time( crucial time for my program).

2. Use some types of postgres joins, but the samples in documentation disappoints me.

Is there exists some method or rule which could make this update/transfer in short period of time. Maybe I should to use some advanced big data libraries such as SparkSQL or something else.

Regards,
qwew

Comment: Why would you not leave the table be and do a join when you need `fourth_column`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek I do not know how to do it. I couldn't find a way in postgres documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you already have a system in place that successfully populates `first_table` and `second_table`.

If that is the case, then join the two tables when you need to bring the data together:

```
select f.id, f.first_column, f.second_column, f.third_column, s.fourth_column
  from first_table f
  join second_table s
    on s.id = f.id
 where f.first_column = 200
   and s.fourth_column = 110
```

If the tables have 100 million records, then I assume you are using some criteria to limit what rows come back as in the `where` clause in my example.